# How can I clean and text mine a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scikit-learn, python-re

I have a piece of code that extracts the texts from several PDFs and puts them into a list of lists, called pages_text

Now I have my text in lists, I'm trying to clean it of special characters using this code:

```
for i in len(pages_text):
    pages_text[i] = pages_text[i].lower()
    re.sub('™', "", pages_text[i])
    re.sub('[\n]', "", pages_text[i])
    re.sub("'\n'", "", pages_text[i])
    re.sub('[™]', '', pages_text[i])
    re.sub('ﬂ', '', pages_text[i])
    re.sub('\nŒ', '', pages_text[i])
    re.findall(r"\s+", pages_text[i])
    print(pages_text)
```

But it isn't quite working to remove the special characters.

My question is :

1. Can someone help me troubleshoot my cleaning process?

Grateful for any help pointing me in the right direction!

**Edited for concision and clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python strings are not mutable, and `re.sub` does not modify them in-place.  You have to replace the original string with the new one returned by `re.sub()`.

Also, instead of using multiple regular expressions you can much more efficiently combine these into a single regexp.  For example:

```
special_chars_re = re.compile('[™ﬂŒ\n]')
for idx, line in enumerate(pages_text):
    pages_text[idx] = special_chars_re.sub('', line.lower())
```

For the rest of your questions, please keep posts to one question at a time to not risk your question being closed as too broad.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks so much!